# CDI module in EJB-jar deployed in an EAR

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi, weld, open-liberty

I have the following setup:

- EAR

  - `app.war` (WAR module)

    - `@Inject SomeService` --> works!
    - depends on `ejb`
  - `ejb.jar` (EJB module)

    - `@Stateless SomeServiceBean`

      - `@Inject Foo` --> **does not work**
    - beans.xml, bean-discovery-mode="all"
    - depends on `tools`
    - MANIFEST: Class-Path: lib/tools.jar
  - `tools.jar` (JAR module with CDI)

    - `@ApplicationScoped FooBean`
    - beans.xml, bean-discovery-mode="all"

How can I configure an ejb-module to be able to inject classes with CDI that are located in a dependent jar? Currently, CDI is throwing:

`WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type SomeService with qualifiers @Default`

This exception only appears if I try to inject `Foo` into `SomeServiceBean`. Without `Foo` all is working fine.

Here is an excerpt from the [CDI spec](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/2.0/cdi-spec-2.0.html#bean_archive_ee):

> In an application deployed as an ear, the container searches every bean archive bundled with or referenced by the ear, including bean archives bundled with or referenced by wars, Jakarta Enterprise Bean jars and rars contained in the ear. The bean archives might be library jars, Jakarta Enterprise Bean jars or war WEB-INF/classes directories.

It should therefor be possible to use CDI beans referenced Jakarta Enterprise Bean (ejb-module) jars, no?

I am using Mavens EJB plugin to build the EJB module:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <ejbVersion>3.2</ejbVersion>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
          <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I am using Mavens EAR plugin to configure the EAR:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.2.0</version>
<configuration>
    <defaultLibBundleDir>lib/</defaultLibBundleDir>
    <modules>
        <jarModule>
            <groupId>some.group</groupId>
            <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
        </jarModule>
        <ejbModule>
            <groupId>some.group</groupId>
            <artifactId>ejb</artifactId>
            <uri>/ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</uri>
        </ejbModule>
        <webModule>
            <groupId>some.group</groupId>
            <artifactId>app</artifactId>
            <uri>/app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war</uri>
            <contextRoot>/app</contextRoot>
        </webModule>
    </modules>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

Application server is OpenLiberty. Here is the server.xml

```
<server description="Cups Liberty server">

<featureManager>
    <feature>webProfile-8.0</feature>
</featureManager>

<variable name="default.http.port" defaultValue="9080"/>
<variable name="default.https.port" defaultValue="9443"/>

<httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
              host="*"
              httpPort="${default.http.port}"
              httpsPort="${default.https.port}"/>

<enterpriseApplication id="open-liberty-cup-ear"
                       location="ear.ear"
                       name="open-liberty-cup-ear"/>

</server>
```

Comment: What features do you have enabled (in your server.xml, etc.)?

Comment: @ScottKurz I added the `server.xml` to my post.

Comment: Enabling <feature>jakartaee-8.0</feature> results in the same behaviour.

Comment: Do you have a recreate project you could link to?  E.g. on GitHub ?     With all the different modules and the config on each (of the EAR plugin, etc.) it might be helpful for someone to try to build it themselves.